# Flutter receives 422 response from Fastapi when posting a PNG file

Tags: flutter, dart, http-post, fastapi, flutter-image

I have created a working localhost API with FastAPI. The POST takes a PNG, does some image processing and returns a PNG as expected when I click the 'try it out' button in the FastAPI generated docs:
[image: successful localhost api call for png]
The curl post command shows as follows:

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://localhost:8345/api/predict' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F 'file=@test_img.png;type=image/png'
```

The image File is successfully retrieved from the image picker library. (Where the image1 object has been initialized as `File image1;` in the app page's class.

```
Future getImage() async {
    var imageTmp = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      image1 = imageTmp;
      print('Image Path $image1');
    });
  }
```

I tried to emulate the API call with the below function in Flutter.

```
  doUpload() {
    /*
    curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://192.168.178.26:8345/api/predict' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F 'file=@test_img.png;type=image/png'

     */
    var request = http.MultipartRequest(
      'POST',
      Uri.parse("http://<my locally hosted ip>:8345/api/predict"),
    );
    Map<String, String> headers = {"Content-type": "multipart/form-data"};
    request.files.add(
      http.MultipartFile(
        'image',
        image1.readAsBytes().asStream(),
        image1.lengthSync(),
        filename: 'filename',
        contentType: MediaType('image', 'png'),
      ),
    );
    request.headers.addAll(headers);
    print("request: " + request.toString());
    request.send().then((value) => print(value.statusCode));
  }
```

When I run the `doUpload()` function, a POST is successfully sent to the localhost API, but it returns a 422 error 'unprocessable entity'.
What I tried:

- I tried to set the image type in doUpload to jpg, jpeg, but I keep getting a 422 error.
- I tried looking up where the image_picker is supposed to store the temporary file to see if it's stored correctly, but when I look at the generated filepath, I don't see the actual file and tmp folder:
  filepath: `File: '/data/user/0/<my package name>/cache/image_picker3300408791299772729jpg'`

looking at my local UI filepath, I see:
[image]

It shows no folder named cache, so I can't inspect it like this. However, the image picker saves it with a jpg at the end (not .jpg, is this normal?)

- I also tried adding this debugger function to my fastAPI server.py, but I'm not sure how I can inspect the resulting data in the current flutter code:
  https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/#use-the-requestvalidationerror-body
  The resulting `value` has properties like statusCode and reason, but I don't see a full json output option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To mimic that `curl` command exactly, use this: (I've used the convenience constructor for simplicity)

```
  final request = http.MultipartRequest(
    'POST',
    Uri.parse('http://<my locally hosted ip>:8345/api/predict'),
  );

  request.files.add(
    await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
      'file', // NOTE - this value must match the 'file=' at the start of -F
      image1.path,
      contentType: MediaType('image', 'png'),
    ),
  );

  final response = await http.Response.fromStream(await request.send());

  print(response.body);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks a bunch! It returned
`INFO:     <my local phone ipv4> - "POST /api/predict HTTP/1.1" 200 OK`
I only had additionally change the function to 
`doUpload() async {` due to your `await`. Which is probably for the better anyway :)

Comment: Also thanks for explaining what made it work, with the `file` comment